# Using ng2-admin angular-2, can we use one route for multiple links/menus

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My requirement is:
**Using ng2-admin angular-2 library, can we use one route for multiple links/menus, and depends on link clicked we should set a flag and then show div content accordingly. Does it possible in angualr-2?**

initially i used different routes for every link/menu but inside div i have iframe and his src loading every time when we clicked on links/menus, so to avoid this effect i am going to show and hide div and for this all iframe should be on same page/html/component and accordingly flag value will set to div hide and show, and redirecting to that route from other menu clicks.

Can any one help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with something like this :

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
 route.url.subscribe((url) => updateIfram(url));
}
```

But I'd rather do it with a component by iFrame target, and using the router to manage the activated component.

Regards